# Yup validation - pass custom error message for a field

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, yup

I have a Yup validation schema defined for my React Hook Form. I am also able to display error messages below the field for any Yup validation failures (client-side)

Now, on Submit of the form, I get some field error message from the API and want to display the same below the field. For some reason, I am unable to get that to work via the setError.

Is it possible to leverage the Yup validation schema to only display the field error message (I already have from the server) and not perform any further validation (since in this case, field is already validated by the server...assume some business logic error)

Comment: Would you mind posting a reproducible example of the code to help us better understand what you're asking?

Answer (score 0):

this is way to pass custom massages in Yup validation library easily . it is use with formik library to validate form easily in React JS & React Native

yup libaray is use in both react native and react js

Example - name:name:yup.string().min(3,'To Short').required('Name is must')
email: yup.string().email('Invalid Email').required('Email is must'),

```
 'Email is must' , 'To Short' this are custom massage
```

Comment: Thanks...actually I am aware of the Yup schema definition. But looking at ways to pass/display custom error messages...i.e. something which ctx.createError gives...